# Importing only particular json file data into the python script

Tags: python, json, import

```
empjson:
{
    "emp1": {
        "name":"abc",
        "id":"123",
        "home-add":"USA",
    },

    "emp2": {
        "name": "def",
        "id":"456",
        "home-add":"Can",
    },
    "emp3": {
        "name": "ghi",
        "id": "789",
        "home-add": "UK",
    },

}
```

Python script

```
dbjson = open('empjson.json', 'r')
jsondata = dbjson.read()
obj = json.loads(jsondata)
print(obj)
print(obj.emp1['name'],True)
```

Question: I can print the complete employee data but how do I just print particular employee data?
When I try doing this, it says attribute error.
And on the line print (obj.emp1['name'], True) can I save this data in a string?

Comment: print(obj.emp2['name'],True) is what I am trying to print

Comment: Use `['emp1']` instead of `.emp1`  i.e. `obj['emp1']['name']`

Comment: Thanks John, this worked.